# North Korean themed theme parks

Tags: amusement-parks, east-asia

Are there any theme parks themed on modern-day North Korea, akin to Stalinworld, located in Japan, South Korea, or Mongolia?

I know that going on a government-run guided tour of North Korea is pretty much a theme park version of life in the country, but I don't want to visit North Korea at the present time.

Comment: North Korea is a horror show, not a punch line. Hey, while we're at it, are there any Partition of India-themed parks, or maybe one about the Spanish Civil War in Belgium or something? There's a land where you walk around shooting clerics and another where you bomb villagers, plus there's the souvenir Falangist hat.

Comment: There are plenty of concentration camps available for touring in Europe if you want to see what it's like in North Korea. Human atrocities are the same everywhere.

Comment: @JonathanReez are there any communist concentration camps, or only Nazi ones?

Comment: Both are available for tours. I don't think they are particularly different.

Answer (score 4):

I think the closest you would get to a North Korean themed park and North Korea itself would be [Imjingak Pyeonghoa-Nuri Park](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g1872665-d3164751-Reviews-Imjingak_Pyeonghoa_Nuri_Park-Paju_Gyeonggi_do.html) and other nearby attractions.

There's nothing like [Splendid China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splendid_China_(Florida)) out there.